# How to make a margin like on Apple support site

Tags: html, css

I would like to have those margins on the left and right like Apple does on its support articles (example: [support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306))

Now when I try to make it with the css elements margin-right and margin-left this kinda does not work as the content section must not vary in size but rather the margins.

my css:

```
.margin {margin-left: 400px; margin-right: 400px;}
```

It also dows not work when I set a width to the content section and make `margin-left and right: auto;`

my html:

```
<div class:"margin">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `class:"margin"` is incorrect. It would be `class="margin"`

Comment: use the inspector of the browser. This is quite basic CSS: `max-width: 960px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it kind of this:

```
<div class="wrapper>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 100%
}
.content {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

> margin: 0 auto;

centers the .content div inside .wrapper.